# Apostrophe gets interpreted as char no matter what in C++

Tags: c++, replace, char, backslash

I'm having an issue. Here is the code if you need it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
std::string findthis = "I\'m";
std::string input;
int index;
std::string sub = "Hi";
int main() {
    while (true) {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if ((index = input.find(findthis)) != std::string::npos) {
            input.replace(index, 2, sub);
            std::cout << input << ", I'm dad!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, it is a simple dad bot program, but I'm learning about search and replace in C++. However, if i try to execute the code, Here is the result:

```
(me) I'm test
(output) Him test, I'm dad!
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You're asking to replace 2 chars. `I'm` is not two chars

Comment: "Apostrophe gets interpreted as char" what else should it be?

Answer (score 3):

`"I\'m"` is 3 characters in length: `I` `'` `m` (FYI, you don't need to escape `'` in a *string* literal, only in a *character* literal).  But you are telling `replace()` to replace only 2 characters, not 3 characters.  So, you are replacing `I` with `H`, and `'` with `i`, but leaving `m` unchanged. That is why you are seeing `Him` instead of `Hi` in the output.

You need to change this:

`input.replace(index, 2, sub);`

To this instead:

`input.replace(index, findthis.size(), sub);`

---

That being said, there are a few other changes you should make, as well:

- `findthis` and `sub` should be declared `const`.
- `input` and `index` should not be global variables.
- `index` should be `std::string::size_type` instead of `int`.
- `while (true) { std::getline(std::cin, input); ... }`
  should be changed to:
  `while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) { ... }`

[Demo](https://ideone.com/34eAhV)